# ACPI not working on Debian Stretch on machine CSL Intel NUC Celeron N2820-3

Tags: debian, acpi

I'm using a CSL Intel NUC Celeron N2820-3 machine since 2015 January as a file server at home. It worked well with Wheezy and Jessie, but some months ago I've updated it to Stretch.

Since the update I can neither shut it down nor can I restart it, using:

- shutdown -h now
- shutdown -r now

The acpid deamon is running, so I have no clue what the problem can be. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What happens after you run those commands? Anything in the logs anywhere?

Comment: @thrig: To be honest I don't even know which log to check. I just had a look at /var/log/syslog, but didn't see any errors during the shutdown, only lines with "Stopped" or "Stopping".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Updated the BIOS to [FYBYT10H.86A](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26629/BIOS-Update-FYBYT10H-86A-?product=78953), but that didn't help in itself. I also had to reset the BIOS settings to default. Now shutdown, restart and even wake-on-LAN works well.